# How do I unwrap the strings I am using for my label?

Tags: ios, json, swift, option-type

I have labels in my UI and they are consistently showing up as "Optional(xxxxxxx)". How do I fix this?

Here I make local objects from JSON data:

```
func populateCurrentIssue() {
    if populatingCurrentIssue {
        return
    }

    populatingCurrentIssue = true

    Alamofire.request(GWNetworking.Router.Issue).responseJSON() { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {

                var nodeIDArray : [Int]

                if (JSON .isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)) {

                    for node in JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                        let nodeIDValue = node.0
                        var lastItem : Int = 0

                        if let issueElement : IssueElement = IssueElement(title: "init", nodeID: 0, timeStamp: 0, imageURL: "init", author: "init", issueNumber: "init", volumeNumber: "init", articleContent: "init", coverImageInteger: "init", coverImage: UIImage()) {

                            issueElement.title = node.1["title"] as! String
                            issueElement.nodeID = Int(nodeIDValue)!


                            issueElement.author = String(node.1["author"])

                            lastItem = self.currentIssueObjects.count


                            self.currentIssueObjects.addObject(issueElement)

                            // Sorting with decreasing timestamp from top to bottom.
                            let timestampSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)

                            let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.currentIssueObjects.count).map {
                                NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0) }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.currentIssueTableView.reloadData()

                }

            }

        }

        self.populatingCurrentIssue = false
}
}
```

Here I populate my table view cell with data:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {

    let row = indexPath.row

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueArticlesTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CurrentIssueArticlesTableViewCell else {

        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueArticlesTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EditorialsTableViewCell
    }

    if let currentIssueObject = currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? IssueElement {

        let author = currentIssueObject.author

        let nodeID = currentIssueObject.nodeID ?? 0

        cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel!.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
        cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel!.text = author


        else {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else {
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

[image: d]

JSON data:

```
"637": {
"title": "Syd Editorial: The Truth Behind Disney Princesses",
"nid": "637",
"type": "article",
"created": "1444923059",
"revision_timestamp": "1444923059",
"disqus": {
"domain": "****domainname*****
"url": "****the API URL***",
"title": "Syd Editorial: The Truth Behind Disney Princesses",
"identifier": "node/637",
"status": false
},
"image_url": null,
"video_url": null,
"author": "Sydney Wilson",
"issue": "Issue 6",
"volume": "Volume 50",
"issue_int": "6",
"volume_int": "50",
"html_content": "<p>Earlier this week I was spending my time perusing facebook and generally wasting valuable time I could be using to better my life and came across a BuzzFeed article a ‘friend’ had shared: Belle Was Literally the Fucking Worst. After immediately unfriending that anonymous friend (sorry, Mom), because I don’t need that kind of negativity in my life, I carried on with my mindless internet clicking. But it nagged at the back of my mind - what could Belle, the princess praised for her smarts, and more importantly, beauty, have done to make her so hated? So I held my breath, bracing myself for the worst kind of bullshit and clicked the clickbait article, like a fish, I was hooked and they reeled me in. I’ve never spent so much time researching Disney Princesses since I wished I was one (who am I kidding, I still wish I was one).&nbsp;<br />\r\n\tGet this, Belle was actually a rich little overdramatic brat who doesn’t care at all who she hurts, and they got all that incredible insight just from the first song. She uses her beauty to get books and bully farm animals - who does she think she is, making fun of poor illiterate sheep. She is horrible to the furniture, who only want to make her stay pleasant, and then has the gall to feel victimized for getting in trouble for ignoring the rest of the giant castle to explore literally the only room she was asked to avoid. Belle is actually the fucking worst, or is she?<br />\r\n\tSo that got me wondering, are all the Disney Princesses actually horrible people in disguise. I can’t imagine there being anything wrong with them at all, but even still I decided to revisit my personal favourite Disney Princess and see if perhaps she wasn’t exactly the role model I thought she was.&nbsp;<br />\r\n\tAriel: &nbsp;“I’m, like, sixteen Dad, I’m an adult. I can do whatever I want.”&nbsp;<br />\r\n\tI’ve heard that once you start agreeing with the parents in Disney films your childhood is officially over. I must have reached that point, because if you really think about it, Ariel is just some whiney guppy who actually has no understanding of how life really works. She misses the party dedicated entirely to her, so she could ‘find treasure’ with her ‘friend’. Looks like someone ditched a family occasion to score some drugs. While high on the latest swamp drug ‘C Weed’ she falls in love with a man who belongs to an entirely different species and is surprised when her dad gets pissed of and destroys her paraphernalia.&nbsp;<br />\r\n\tI’m sure I could go on for pages about how disney princesses are actually shit, and mayhaps one day I will, but fortunately for you today is not that day. Just heed my warning, if you still want to be a disney princess, while I commend you, your priorites are shit and you should probably seek some kind of professional for your mental or drug related issues. &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>",
"article_category": {
"name": "Editorials",
"machine_name": "editorials"
},
"cover_image": "0",
"slider_item": "0",
"tags": [
"Disney",
"Role Models"
]
},
```

Comment: Reduce your code to a minimum, only post what is essential to your problem

Comment: I cleaned things up.

Comment: can you post just labels where you wanna unwrap?

Comment: We need the definition of currentIssueObject

Comment: Is this the one? cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel!.text = author

Comment: If so replace it with this - cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel.text! = author

Comment: I want to unwrap cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel and also the text in my web view (in my detail view controller, summoned by my cell). I just tried what you told me to do and it didn't change anything. Everything still appears as an optional.

Comment: The definition of currentIssueObject is in the second sample of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a dictionary returns an Optional.

This is the case with your `node.1["author"]` in `String()` in `populateCurrentIssue()`.

Solution:

```
if let author = node.1["author"] as? String {
    issueElement.author = author
}
```

Comment: I FREAKING LOVE YOU! IT WORKED!

Comment: I have literally been trying to get rid of this for 3 weeks!

Comment: Hey just noticed that you're French. That makes two of us. Mais moi j'habite à Montréal :P Merci beaucoup, tu m'as sauvé la vie. Il était vraiment urgent pour moi de régler ce problème.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an optional value on the author section I believe. If that is so then do this.

```
guard let author = currentIssueObject.author as? String else {
print("author not found")
return cell
}
```

Comment: I get the error "non-void function should return a value" when I use the first one.

Comment: and when I try the second one, I get the error "Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSString'.

Comment: I still get the same error. What should I be returning ?

Comment: Sorry about that forgot to put return cell since you are working inside the table. Edited again.

Answer (score 0):

The Optional(someText) problem would be solved like this:

```
guard let author = currentIssueObject.author else {
    return
}
```

Regrettably you don't get a warning when you assign a wrapped string to a .text property, probably because you're allowed to assign nil to it.

I see some more issues with your code though, let me propose an alternative:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {

    let row = indexPath.row

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueArticlesTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CurrentIssueArticlesTableViewCell else {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueArticlesTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EditorialsTableViewCell
    }

    guard currentIssueObjects.count - 1 > indexPath.row else {
        return cell // There is no safe unwrappy way go get an object from an array, just do a boundaries check
    }

    let currentIssueObject = currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

    guard let author = currentIssueObject.author,
        nodeID = currentIssueObject.nodeID else {
        return cell
    }

    // Always use ?. instead of !. whenever possible, or unwrap first
    cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
    cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel?.text = author

    return cell
}
```

There are many more things that can be improved about your code. I don't think the IssueElement author property should be a nillable String to begin with since you create it through a init.

Also important:

```
Alamofire.request(GWNetworking.Router.Issue).responseJSON() { [weak self] response in
     guard strongSelf = self else {
         return // self doesn't exist anymore when the thread returns
     }
```

Comment: So there are a few possibilities. You need to put a breakpoint right where you receive the data and debug. If you save and load from the same app you might have saved the value Optional(something) first and now you're loading it all the time.

Comment: The author variable is just constantly being shown as Optional(). Even when it goes through the guard let loop I just added, it doesn't get unwrapped.

Comment: Could you paste the JSON response of your web service?

Comment: I just added an example of a JSON node for my API.

Answer (score 0):

`if let author = currentIssueObject.author { //author is unwrapped }`

and this:

`if let nodeID = currentIssueObject.nodeID { //nodeID is unwrapped }`

Comment: for the first solution, I get the error "initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'